# How to copy/clone a hash/object in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clone, javascript-objects

I have a simple object (or hash) in Javascript:

```
var settings = {
  link: 'http://example.com',
  photo: 'http://photos.com/me.jpg'
};
```

I need a copy of it.  Is there a `settings.clone()` type method that will give me another object with the same attributes?  I'm using jQuery, so happy to use a jQuery utility method if one exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying an Object in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: IMHO this should be renamed 'How to copy/clone a hash/object in **jquery**'. Then it would be different from the above duplicate.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) an empty object with the original one; that way, everything will simply be copied:

```
var clone = $.extend({}, settings);
```

---

Extending some filled object with another, e.g.:

```
$.extend({a:1}, {b:2})
```

will return:

```
{a:1, b:2}
```

---

With the same logic:

```
$.extend({}, {foo:'bar', test:123})
```

will return:

```
{foo:'bar', test:123}
```

i.e. effectively a clone.

Comment: incorrect; contained objects are still passed by reference, and not deep-cloned, e.g. a={aa:{aaa:3}}; b=$extend({},a}; a.aa.aaa=4;  b.aa.aaa==4 !!

Comment: @BerryTsakala: Since JQuery 1.1.4 you can use [`extend(true, ...)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) to create deep copies.

Answer (score 33):

In a non jQuery way.

```
var newObj = {};

Object.keys(settings).forEach(function(key) {
     newObj[ key ] = settings[ key ];
});
```

This copies only the top-level properties. To copy hashes with nested objects as property values, you will need to use a recursive function.

**NB:** The `Object.keys(settings)` avoids the need for calling `settings.hasOwnProperty(key)`.

Comment: +1 Just to make sure, `hasOwnProperty` would be a good addition. (+1 tomorrow as I reached vote limit :))

Comment: I modified the code so that `hasOwnProperty` is no longer required.

Answer (score 4):

```
var clone = $.extend(true, {}, settings);
```

Set first argument to true.

EDIT: First argument `true` signifies deep copy. For given example in original question there is no need for deep copy since there are simple immutable key-value pairs. For question in title - as a general case - use deep copy. Otherwise you get half-copy.

Comment: You only need `true` if you want a deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want jQuery extend, which can copy an object for you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

```
function clone(hash) {
  var json = JSON.stringify(hash);
  var object = JSON.parse(json);

  return object;
}
```

It may not be the most optimized option but it can be handy for some scenarios.

Comment: for most uses this is pretty good .. but it will miss keys with `undefined` as the value

Answer (score 1):

Underscore.js [also has an extend function](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) if you are not using jQuery:

> **extend** `_.extend(destination, *sources)`  Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, and
>   return the destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will
>   override properties of the same name in previous arguments.
>
> ```
> _.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50});
> => {name: 'moe', age: 50}
> ```

Comment: Or even more expressive : `var new_obj = _.clone( old_obj );`