# Strange behavior of "delete" keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object "a" and I assign it to another variable named "b". 
Now I delete some property values from "b" using delete keyword. It deletes that property from both objects "a" and "b". Why is that?

P.S: I am beginner in javascript. go easy on me.

Code: -

```js
let a = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3
}

let b = a;
console.log(a);   // output   { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
delete b.a;
console.log(a)   // Expected output { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }    -- Actual output { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Comment: this is pass by reference, here both `a` and `b` will have same value so it is deleting from same value

Comment: Both "b" and "a" are variables pointing to the *same* object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy/clone a hash/object in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113865/how-to-copy-clone-a-hash-object-in-jquery)

Comment: you ar referring a to b. u r not copying values of a into b array. it can be b = {...a}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more related to the fact that some types are assigned by value and others by reference.

In a quick summary

**Primitive types** are assigned by value (Boolean, Null, Undefined, Number, String, Symbol (new in ES 6))

**Non Primitive types** are assigned by reference (Object, Array , Functions)

---

#### Example: Primitive types

```
let a = 1;
let b = a;

console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 1

b = 2;

console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2
```

As you can see changing `b` will not affect `a` because number is assigned by value.

---

#### Example: Non Primitive types

```
let a = { name: 'Amr' };
let b = a;

console.log(a); // { name: 'Amr' };
console.log(b); // { name: 'Amr' };

b.name = "John";

console.log(a); // { name: 'John' };
console.log(b); // { name: 'John' };
```

As you can see changing `b` affected the value of `a` because it is assigned by reference, this is similar to your example, the issue is not related to `delete` but it is related to the fact that objects are assigned by reference so deleting key from `b` will affect `a`

---

#### Cloning:

in some situations you will need to clone your non primitive type object and not mutating the current one, you can do that using the following way:

1. ES5  `var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);` OR
   `var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`
2. ES6 `var clone = { ...obj };`

now updating `clone` will not affect `obj`

---

Finally You can read more about this topic in this [link](https://github.com/amrlabib/javascript-essentials-how-why/blob/master/valueOrReference.md) it can give you a better understanding on how this works with memory assignment illustrations

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have understood it. :). Can I assign non primitive types by value?

Comment: You are welcome ... probably you are asking about how to clone your object ... i have edited the answer to explain that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
let b = a;
```

You just pass reference of the object a to b. So a and b points to the same reference. Therefore changes made in any one of them will reflect in other.

Basically you have something in the memory as:

```
a:ref12345−−−+
             |
             |
             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 
             +−−−>|  (object)   |                 
             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 
             |    | prop1: "a"  |                 
             |    | prop2: "b"  |
b :ref12345−−+    | prop3: "c"  |
                  |             |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Answer (score 0):

Java script array are copied through copy by reference. So if you edit the copied array, the original array will be changed.
You can use

let b = a. slice()

Or

Spread operator in ES6.
let b = [... a]